# How to filter data by field that contains specific string in ElasticSearch, Node Js?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have simple Node Js application.

I want get filtered data by **Path** field, that contains '**get**' word.

For example my data is like below:

```
"_source": {
    "time": "2020-03-12T01:25:41.61836-07:00",
    "level": "Info",
    "info": {
      "IpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
      "Path": "/api/test/getTest/1",
      "QueryString": "",
      "UserAgent": "",
      "LogDate": "2020-03-12T08:25:41.6220806Z",
      "Username": "cavidan.aliyev",
      "NodeId": "123456"
    }
```

In other words my entity object's structure like as below:

```
{
   time,
        level,
        info: {
          IpAddress,
          Path,
          QueryString,
          UserAgent,
          LogDate,
          Username,
          NodeId
        }
}
```

My query is like below:

```
 client.search({
                index: collectionName,
                body: { 
                    from: (params.currentPage - 1) * params.pageSize,
                    size: params.pageSize,
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": mustArr,
                            "filter": [ 
                                {
                                   "match_all": {}
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, function (err, res) {
                if (err) { 
                    reject(err);
                }
                else { 
                    let result = res.hits.hits. map(x => x._source);
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });
```

How I can filter data by **Path** field, that contains '**get**' word?

Please help me, thanks

Comment: Could you share your mapping. Is `info` a `nested` type or an `object` type? If you can share the mapping information of the document, it'd be great!

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal Hi, thanks you for comment. I already edit my post.

Comment: So basically ES has two different types for `json inside a json` structure in either as `nested` type or `object` type. I've mentioned solutions for both the types in my answer. You can get to know from the mapping of the index if `info` is a `nested` type using `GET <your_index_name>/_mapping`. If its not then probably its an object type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [Wildcard Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) inside the filter query you have. I'm assuming that you are making use of [`Standard Analyzer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) for `info.Path` field.

Note that for the sake of simplicity I've just mentioned what should be going inside the `filter` query you have.

### If `info.Path` is [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) type:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {                        <--- Note this
        "nested": {
          "path": "info",
          "query": {
            "wildcard": {
              "info.Path": {
                "value": "*get*"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### If `info.Path` is [`object`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) type:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {                        <--- Note this
        "wildcard":{
          "info.Path": "*get*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Important Note:** Wildcard search slows the query performance, and if you have a control on the Elasticsearch's index, then you should definitely look at `ngram` search model, which creates `n-gram` tokens at index-time as mentioned in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) link.

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want returned data with "get" keywords, your wildcard should type into the `must_not`. 
For example:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
 {
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "must_not":{
          "filter": {                       
             "wildcard":{
               "info.Path": "*get*"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```